# XML element ordering by inner element with XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, element

Say I have the following XML and I want XSLT transformation which would change the ordering of `<invoice>` elements by the value of `<paymentType>` element. How should the XSLT look like?

Input:

```
<invoices>
  <invoice>
    <paymentType>
      1
    </paymentType>
  </invoice>
  <invoice>
    <paymentType>
      2
    </paymentType>
  </invoice>
  <invoice>
    <paymentType>
      1
    </paymentType>
  </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Desired output:

```
<invoices>
  <invoice>
    <paymentType>
      1
    </paymentType>
  </invoice>
  <invoice>
    <paymentType>
      1
    </paymentType>
  </invoice>
  <invoice>
    <paymentType>
      2
    </paymentType>
  </invoice>
</invoices>
```

**EDIT:**
As suggest I am providing my current XSLT, which also includes the solution from marked answer in this thread. Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/invoices">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice">
            <xsl:sort select="paymentType" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt and save us the necessity to write everything from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/invoices">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice">
            <xsl:sort select="paymentType" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Hopefully you know the rest.